# Android Studio Loading Texture error

Tags: java, android, libgdx, textures

I have this strange error where I can't load any textures anymore. The assets that I used are fine, but when I try to add new assets, it throws me this:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 9855
Process: com.NeverMind.MainClass.android, PID: 18482
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: bg.png
     at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:140)
     at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.TextureData$Factory.loadFromFile(TextureData.java:98)
     at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:100)
     at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:92)
     at com.NeverMind.DontFall.android.MainClass.create(MainClass.java:200)
     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:241)
     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1520)
     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1248)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error loading pixmap: decoder init failed for stream
     at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Gdx2DPixmap.<init>(Gdx2DPixmap.java:57)
     at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:138)
     at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.TextureData$Factory.loadFromFile(TextureData.java:98) 
     at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:100) 
     at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:92) 
     at com.NeverMind.DontFall.android.MainClass.create(MainClass.java:200) 
     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:241) 
     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1520) 
     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1248) 

I didn't do anything stupid. I also tried to trick him and put the new texture with the name of an old one and it didn't work. This is the first time this happens, I have thousands of lines in the code.
```

Comment: Without seeing any of your code I tihnk that this threat might be helpful to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25426087/e-androidruntime-fatal-exception-main

Comment: @Dan C, could you show the section of code that is causing the exception?

Comment: Behavior and thrown exceptions sound very close to this: http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=18368. Check out the 3 suggestions offered there (particularly #3)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the bit depth. It needs to be smaller.