# App was working but now closing unexpectedly

Tags: java, android

Yesterday my app `shopapp` was working perfectly as it should. But today when I am opening it in AVD it is closing unexpectedly. I checked the error log in Log Cat but it seems a bit confusing to me.

I checked the [duplicate question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25426087/e-androidruntime-fatal-exception-main) but that contains the error log caused by `findViewById`.

**Error Log:**

```
--------- beginning of crash
    2019-01-22 12:21:52.836 4855-4855/com.local.xspac.shopapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.local.xspac.shopapp, PID: 4855
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.local.xspac.shopapp/com.local.xspac.shopapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.local.xspac.shopapp.MainActivity> cannot be instantiated
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2567)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
         Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.local.xspac.shopapp.MainActivity> cannot be instantiated
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2557)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

**MainActivity:**

```
package com.local.xspac.shopapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public abstract class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String[] listviewTitle = new String[] {
            "Shop One", "Shop Two", "Shop Three", "Shop Four",
            "Shop Five", "Shop Six", "Shop Seven", "Shop Eight",
    };
    String[] listviewURL = new String[] {
            "https://google.com", "https://bing.com", "https://yahoo.com", "https://duckduckgo.com", "https://stackoverflow.com/",
            "https://thehackernews.com", "https://techviral.net", "https://amazon.in",
    };
    String[] listviewShortDescription = new String[]{
            "Shop One Short Description", "Shop Two Short Description", "Shop Three Short Description", "Shop Four Short Description",
            "Shop Five Short Description", "Shop Six Short Description", "Shop Seven Short Description", "Shop Eight Short Description",
    };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        List<HashMap<String, String>> aList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
            hm.put("listview_title", listviewTitle[i]);
            hm.put("listview_discription", listviewShortDescription[i]);
            hm.put("listview_url", listviewURL[i]);

            aList.add(hm);
        }
        //String[] from = {"listview_image", "listview_title", "listview_description"};
        String[] from = {"listview_url", "listview_title", "listview_discription"};
        int[] to = {R.id.listview_item_url, R.id.listview_item_title, R.id.listview_item_short_description};

        //int[] to = {R.id.listview_item_title, R.id.listview_item_short_description};

        SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.listview_activity, from, to);
        ListView androidListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        androidListView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
        androidListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
                //
            }
        });
    }
    public void buttonClick(View view) {
        String currentURL = null;
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
        TextView child = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.listview_item_url);
        currentURL = child.getText().toString();
        Intent logwebview = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WebViewActivity.class);
        logwebview.putExtra("CurrentUrL",String.valueOf(currentURL));
        startActivity(logwebview);
    }
    public void fetchClick (View view) {
        Intent fetchDetails = new Intent(MainActivity.this, API.class);
        startActivity(fetchDetails);
    }
}
```

Comment: show your code please.

Comment: Can you confirm that the activity is registered in manifest.xml

Comment: Added MainActivity class. Yes! it is registered in manifest.xml

Comment: why is your activity class `abstract`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo

**Don't**

```
public abstract class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
```

**Do**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
```

Comment: Oh. I should remove `abstract`?

Comment: @Strange yes. Kindly remove. Clean-Rebuild-Run